# What would be the correct way to write this if statement in javascript? DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, if-statement, children

Hello I have a problem where im trying to remove all children, if children are present inside an element. I figure a statement could be written as "if child nodes > 1 remove all children" but I dont know the correct way of formatting this. Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean you don't now how to format this? Are you saying you don't know how to write a loop? It's as simple as `while(parent.firstChild) { parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild); }`

Answer (score 1):

Should be straight forward. Look at [`hasChildNodes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.hasChildNodes)

```
if(node.hasChildNodes()) {
    // insert logic here
} else {
    // something else instead
}
```

#### Direct from MDN:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");

if ( foo.hasChildNodes() ) { 
  foo.removeChild( foo.childNodes[0] );
}
```

In this case, `childNodes` is an array. Meaning it has a `length` property **hint hint, wink wink, nudge nudge**

Comment: This would only remove the first child, OP would like all child nodes removed. I think the loop in the comments would do better

Comment: @HMR Notice the **hint hint, wink wink, nudge nudge** part of the answer

Comment: Oh, sorry... I see now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myNode = document.getElementById("Your ID");
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
    }
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves OP problem.